# Get values for 2 arguments from 1 equation

Tags: matlab

I have this equation: `p = (1 + (q-1)*B*T) ^ (-1/q-1)`

The values p, T are known and the diagram p - T makes curbe. I want to calculate q and B so that curbe be as close to straight line is posible.

Some values are:

```
T    p
1    0,999147061
2    0,997121331
3    0,994562513
```

Is there any way to make matlab (or sth else) to give me the values of B and q ?

Comment: If you have the 'Symbolic Math Toolbox', use 'solve'.

Comment: You seem to have two conflicting questions. You say that values of `p` are known (by which I assume you also mean fixed), but then you say that you want to modify the equation to make the graph of `p` vs. `T` a straight line. If you want to find the parameters of that equation (`B`, `q`) that make it best fit the data (`T`, `p`) then you can use an optimisation function, e.g., `lsqnonlin`. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're asking.